# Lightweight tool to detect Encoding, Newline-type, Delimiter, Encapsulation and Data Types in CSV files

Tags: csv, flat-file, data-cleaning

After writing [this article](https://theonemanitdepartment.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/the-absolute-minimum-everyone-working-with-data-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-file-types-encoding-delimiters-and-data-types-no-excuses/) on the ins-and-outs of CSV files, I've gotten curious if any tool exists to automatically analyze "CSV files" (delimiter separated flat text files) to suggest the most likely Encoding, Newline-type, Delimiter, Encapsulation, Escape character, and Data Types being used.

I'm aware that this will always be guesses, but a tool that checks for inconsistencies when assuming a certain Encoding, Delimiter, .... and then reports if any where found, would already be very useful.

I also assume that large expensive toolboxes like Oracle Data Integrator will probably provide these features. But I'm looking for a lightweight (cheap or free) point and click tool that does this.

If you're considering to suggest Excel, please read the article before commenting ;)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any tool that does exactly what you want, I was waiting to see if some one came up with a better solution.

The [CsvEditors](http://alternativeto.net/software/csvedit/)
should do some of the analysis, some may also validate -

- Rons Editor (Commercial)
- Csv Easy  (Commercial)
- XTabulator (Commercial)
- CsvEd
- dmcsveditor
- ReCsvEditor (**note** - I am the author)

With the **ReCsvEditor** you can start the program with a File-name as a parameter (or search for the file) and it will

- Tell you what it thinks file format is and display the table
- Let you play with various options
- Will try and work out the columns in "Fixed Width"
- ReCsvEditor is Open-Source so the [code](https://sourceforge.net/p/record-editor/code/HEAD/tree/Source/RecordEditor/src/net/sf/RecordEditor/re/util/csv/) is available (CsvAnalyser.java and CheckEncoding.java). The encoding is checked using nsDetector.
- ReCsvEditor can export a "Xml File Schema" for the file (when editing *Edit >>> Save file description* as Xml). This File-Description can be used in JRecord to read the file.

[image]

Limitations:

- At the moment it only looks at the first 16kb during the analysis, I will increase that to at least 128kb shortly.
- Does not display every thing you want (e.g. the Line separator).
- There is no validation.
- More checks need to be added

---

Other Csv-Editor's may be better at determining the type of the file than ReCsvEditor (never checked).

---

There is also the now abandoned [Flat File Checker](http://flat-file.net/index.html) which will validate against a set of criteria.

---

There are various algorithms to determine the Character set e.g.

- [chardet](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/chardet.html)
- [jChardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: That's a great starting point, I'll look into all the tools and see what has most features. Nice to see there's people building tools for this. I'll post my findings here!